# Having an unresolved import error in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to import a module (specifically the discord.py API), and I'm following their documentation on their website (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html). They tell me to use the following command

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

I ran this command in the built-in shell of Visual Studio Code, and it says that it has installed successfully. But back in my code, when I try to import the module, it still gives me the "unresolved import" error. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and a solution? Thank you!

I am using Python 3.9.2

Comment: If you run the code, the error still appears?

Comment: Yes it still does

Comment: Can you show your `import` statement?

Comment: it's simply just "import discord", which is what the documentation has shown

Comment: have you tried to install via your devices shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it incorrectly. I have been using `discord` library in virtual environment so I have installed it too many times.

I have tried these:

```
pip install discord
pip install discord.py
pip install discord discord.py
```

But I can tell you that this will not help. As there is only one way you can install the full library without having any error.

### You have to open VS Code Terminal and type this:

#### If you use a Virtual Environment:

If you are using a virtual environment then you can execute:

```
pip install discord
```

### If you have not using any Virtual Environment:

If you don't use any virtual environment then you can simply use the standard command:

```
python -m pip install discord
```

You can use `python` or `python3` any thing. I would prefer you use `python`. Try using `python` first.

---

That is all and it will help you with your error.

Thank You! :D

Comment: Oh nvm! xD Anyways, do remember this way. Installing `discord.py` doesn't work.